# Google App Engine (Python) redirect not working

Tags: python, redirect

I am trying to execute a redirect but it does not seem to be happening. The XHR outputs that the page has finished loading but my page is not redirected at all. The database has the correct data that I queried for and all.

```
    def post(self):
        modcode = self.request.get("code")
        email = users.get_current_user().email()
        query = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * from ModuleReviews where code =:1 and email =:2", modcode, email).get()

        if query != None:
          self.redirect('/errorR')

        else:
          module = ModuleReviews(code=self.request.get("code"),text=self.request.get("review")) 
          module.text =  self.request.get("review")
          module.code = self.request.get("code")
          module.ratings = self.request.get("ratings")
          module.workload = self.request.get("workload")
          module.diff = self.request.get("diff")
          module.email = users.get_current_user().email()
          module.put()
          self.redirect('/display')
```

Comment: Consider using 'query is not None' instead of 'query != None'. This won't solve your problem, but it is better to write your code like this

Answer (score 0):

If you're using XHR, you will have to get your Javascript handler to do the redirect via `window.location`. However, since you always want a redirect, you should consider whether using Ajax is the right thing at all: just submitting via a normal POST would provide exactly the functionality you want without any Javascript needed.